# Rails 4: how do I get ID on the index page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, has-many

I have Model1, which has "has_many" rel with Model2. What I need is to create form for Model2 under each object on Model1 index page. Lets say I have Tweets and each tweet has form to add comments. I have troubles in understanding how to do it, how to get Tweet id on index page and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like all you need to do to get @comment form working under each @tweet on index page is:

```
- @tweets.each do |tweet|
  = tweet.name `#to show tweet`
  - tweet.comments.each do |comment| `#to show each tweet comment`
    = comment.content 
    = form_for [tweet, Comment.new] do |f| `#form forcomment belonging to this particular tweet`
     = f.text_field :content
     = f.submit
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, Vla :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say tweets has many comments, so create model Tweet and Comment with relationship also create controllers tweets and comments.

In your tweets/index page there are list of tweets, right and script is like this.

```
<% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>
 <%= link_to "show tweet", tweet_path(tweet) %>
<% end %>
```

show tweet link will take you to show page there you will get tweet id from params. Now you can make comment form in this show page as below

```
<%= form_for @comment do |f|%>
 <%= f.text_area :comment %>
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Routes file:

```
resources :tweets do
 resources :comments
end
```

I have just provided you some way to work by giving examples of rails-views, so check action in your controllers properly you will do it.